# Billboardjs chart update visibility of y axis after chart generation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, billboard.js

So I am generating a chart, hidding the y axis, like this:

```
const chart = bb.generate({
  "data": {
        "type": "line",
        "x": "x",
        "columns": columns,
        "axes": {"data1":"y2"},
  },
  "axis":{
       "y": {show: false},
       "y2": {show: true}
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, somewhere in the future, I'm loading a new set of data in this chart, but this time I want to show some data related to the y axis.
I do not know how to tell the chart to make the y axis visibile.

Is there a clean(bb api) way of doing it?
I do not want to regenerate the chart. Or should I just let the y axis be visible in the initial config object and use something like jquery/d3.selection/... to toggle the y axis' visibility?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no exact API for that purpose, but you can make it as follows.

1) At the initialization, control `y Axis` to not be displayed by using CSS `display` property, instead of `axis.y.show=false`.

2) When you load new data, use .load()'s `done` option callback to control the y axis display to be showed again.

Check out the working example below.

```js
const chart = bb.generate({
 data: {
  columns: [
   ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 200, 150, 150],
   ["data2", 30, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
  ]
 },
 axis: {
  y2: {
   show: true
  }
 }
});

function load() {
 chart.load({
  columns: [
      ["data3", 220, 90, 80, 70]
  ],
  done: () => {
      d3.select(".bb-axis.bb-axis-y").style("display", "inherit");
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.bb-axis.bb-axis-y {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>  
  <button onclick="load()">Load data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that was actually almost identical with what I've ended up doing.